# Scaling out the SQL Server backplane for signalr

Tags: sql-server, signalr, service-broker, signalr-backplane

I have already implemented load balanced SignalR services with a SQL Server backplane and it is working fine. Now I want to scale out the backplane across two SQL Servers, but I can't find any documentation specific to SignalR on how to do this. When you setup the SQL Server backplane for SignalR it creates and manages all the tables it needs.

So my questions:

- How do you configure the service brokers between the two SQL Servers for SignalR?
- Does the SignalR SQL Server backplane manage the service broker communications also?
- Is this even possible?

Comment: Technically, "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer", only stores data in tables. Service Broker is only used because it relies on SQL Notifications for the client. And so it's bound to just a single database instance. I think if you want to scale to multiple database or server instances, you'll have to write your backplane that's natively built upon Server Broker.